# Service bindings being ignored

Tags: c#, wcf

Ok, so I've got

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExternalMonitoringBinding" 
                 clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:50000/"
                 closeTimeout="00:00:30">
          <security mode ="None"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="false"/>
        </binding>

      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Loop.Nextmove.ExternalMonitoring.NextmoveMonitorService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExternalMonitoringBinding"
          contract="Loop.Nextmove.ExternalMonitoring.INextmoveCommunicatorMonitorService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NextmoveComunicatorHelpdesk/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>`
```

Whenever I discover the service, the client gets the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_INextmoveCommunicatorMonitorService"
                    closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                    sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NextmoveComunicatorHelpdesk/Service1/"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_INextmoveCommunicatorMonitorService"
                contract="NextmoveMonitoring.INextmoveCommunicatorMonitorService"
                name="WSDualHttpBinding_INextmoveCommunicatorMonitorService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>`
```

Which, as you see, seem to completely ignores the named binding with both it's `clientBaseAddress` and `closeTimeout` values. However, it clearly is doing *something* right, as the security mode gets correctly set to none.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks, was just fixing the formatting when I saw the spaggetti!

Comment: With further searching, seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035846/why-is-my-wcf-service-not-loading-my-binding-config